# How do i remove this extra line?

Tags: modeling, vertices

I was working on a model for a UGC in blender and i made some vertices. But for some reason, when i add a skin modifier it added an extra line. How do I remove it? (Note, I just started using blender.)

[image: The line circled in blue.]

Comment: Can you please add an image indicating the line you're talking about? (You can use the edit button below your question to add it.)

Comment: I drew a blue circle to show the extra line.

Comment: To be honest I don't use the Skin modifier much because I find the results can be rather erattic. It looks as if you must have an extra vertex that's been extruded but it's difficult to see from that image. If you press '/' (forward-slash) that will take you into Local view to show just the glasses. ('/' again to get back out of Local view).

Comment: Alright, thanks dude! :)